# Cooling fresh-baked bread outside in very cold weather

Tags: baking, bread

Currently it is -27C/-17F outside.

Would putting a loaf of freshly-baked bread outside to cool off (quickly) be a good idea or a bad idea?

To clarify, this is for the purposes of cooling it down enough to eat right away, and not for some sort of flash-freezing long-term storage or anything like that.

Comment: Depends, what are you trying to do to it?

Comment: Good question -- I've made an edit to clarify; thanks.

Comment: Surely you could try it and find out? What do you _think_ would happen?

Comment: Yes, try it. I can speculate, but experiment beats speculation.

Comment: Bread doesn't conduct heat very well. In those conditions it's possible the outside would freeze while the inside was still warm. But you might start cooling outside

Comment: Just my opinion but assuming you're asking because you don't want to potentially ruin the loaf as a science experiment, I think this is a risky idea. Bread does a lot of things as it cools off out of the oven - the crust hardens, the inside continues to cook and set, etc. It might not make it inedible to plunge it into sub-zero temperatures right out of the oven, but I'd bet it'll affect the texture of the crust and/or inside noticeably. There's no substitute for time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the dish where you want to eat the bread require cold bread? Otherwise I would say you can eat the bread essentially right out of the oven. Probably put on a glove while cutting it but then the maybe 5 minutes between pulling it out of the oven to the first bite are generally sufficient to get to a temperature where you don't burn yourself. I don't think it will safe you any time to bring the bread outside first and then get it back in almost immediately afterwards.

Note that if you want to freeze the bread for long storage, quick freezing by bringing it outside can be a good idea.

Comment: Bread doesn't cut nicely until fully cooled.  I slice mine to sandwich thickness in the evening, and even after a couple of hours out of the oven, it tears much more than when fully cooled.  Slicing it hot is really only if you want big chunks

Comment: @ChrisH A sharp bread knife helps but you are correct that bread fresh out of the oven doesn't cut easily. Personally I consider the flavor of warm oven fresh bread easily compensates for mishapen slices but I guess that is a personal judgement.

Comment: If I want bread to eat as soon as it comes out of the oven, I make rolls.

Answer (score 2):

I have an outdoor brick oven in NE Canada and I try not to bake when the temp is -20c or less.
This is for the baker not the bread .
Because of the aerated structure of bread it will freeze on the outside before it cools on the inside at -27c. I find even after cooling bread indoors if you put it in the freezer too soon the loaves will curl and collapse a bit as the air inside the loaf shrinks .
I bake until the internal temperature of the loaf is around 208f so the bread is still cooking below the crust when it is removed from the oven .Rapid cooling will shorten the time the loaf has to set internally and you can end up with a gummy middle.

Comment: Thank you for this!  Very helpful.